# Azure service bus: Process 1 message at a time

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-functions, azureservicebus

Right now, we use Azure Service Bus to trigger our function app. The rate of incoming messages is very high, but we want to trigger the function app only one message at a time (to process at our own pace rather than dealing with too many requests error).
How to configure the service bus to only send one message at a time to the receiver?
Here's our basic function app code:

```
    [FunctionName("ServiceBusListener")]
    public void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("myqueue", Connection = "MyConnection")]string queueContent, ILogger log)
    {
        _myService.ProcessMessage(queueContent);
        log.LogInformation($"C# ServiceBus queue trigger function processed message: {queueContent}");
    }
```

Comment: Have you thought about using a queue?

Comment: I have thought about it. That is the worse case scenario. Only thing is I have to manage everything in a queue myself. I was hoping service bus would have a use case to control the consumption rate

Comment: @PeterBons any ideas on using service bus to achieve the same?

Comment: a google search leads me to  MaxMessageBatchSize, may also need to set MaxConcurrentCalls  and MaxConcurrentSessions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't set the service bus to send a message one at a time, rather you set your function app to process service bus messages one at a time. Go to the `host.json` of your function app, then add the following:

```
"extensions": {
        "serviceBus": {
            "messageHandlerOptions": {
                "maxConcurrentCalls": 1
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: just a follow up question: Is this setting dynamically configurable? Let's say I want to prcoess 1 message right now and later want to change to process 3 messages concurrently without stopping the function app. Is that possible?

Comment: @Anwesh rate limiting is currently not supported by Azure functions. You can try using Azure API management together with your function and set the rate limiting from there but I'm not sure if it will apply to queues.